# listpicker performance issue in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

I have the following listpicker I am using in my windows phone app developed in c#.net.But when I tap on the listpicker it takes time to load the items and also after selecting an item in fulltemplatemode it takes time to go back to the page.

```
<tool:ListPicker x:Name="lstPckrCntrlFilterPlaces" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}"  SelectionChanged="lstBoxCntrlFilterPlaces_SelectionChanged_1"  Header="Filter"  FullModeHeader="Filter" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
```

Any suggestions to improve fix this performance issue ?

Comment: I've never seen any inherent performance issues with the control. Can you provide a simple example which reproduces the performance issue you're seeing. Please also confirm what hardware you're seeing this on and the version of the toolkit that you're using.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when listing all songs (just their names as string) on my Lumia 800. There are about 500 items in the list and loading takes about 10 seconds...